# How to save android bitmap and access it indefinitely?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm allowing user to create an image. When they click "create", i save the image on screen to a bitmap and then save the content URI (`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000003643`) returned to local storage so i can read from it later to display the image. I believe this only grants me temporary access as i get the below error after a short while when trying to display the image in another section of the app

```
D/AsyncImageError: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord (pid=20027, uid=10663) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

Does anyone know the best way to save an image and then access it indefinitely whenever I want?

Comment: Save it to a file, such as in `getFilesDir()` on `Context`.

Comment: So i am already doing this but the issue still happens - im running android 13 and use the new READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission to initially let the user choose an image, then according to android docs i don't need a any further permissions to read this images as my app owns it and saved it?

This issue doesn't happen on devices pre android 13, where i use the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission initially

Comment: "i am already doing this" -- not according to your question. Then again, you do not have a [mcve], so we are having to guess. "then according to android docs i don't need a any further permissions to read this images as my app owns it and saved it?" -- `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` is for a read operation. "Save" implies a write operation. I suggest that you start over with a fresh question, one where you explain **in detail** what it is that you are doing, including a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

save bitmap local storage.

```
  try {
                val bitmapDims = ImageUtils.getBitmapDims(BackgroundRemoverActivity.selectedImageUri, this@SmoothActivity
                )
                val i = bitmapDims.outWidth
                var i2 = bitmapDims.outHeight
                val smoothActivity = this@SmoothActivity
                if (i > i2) {
                    i2 = i
                }
                smoothActivity.saveBitmap(i2)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }



    fun saveBitmap(i: Int) {
        dimension = i
        showDialog = false
        val show = ProgressDialog.show(
            this,
            "",
            getString(if (gotoShare) R.string.save_image_ else R.string.processing_image),
            true
        )
        show.setCancelable(false)
        Thread(Runnable {
            val str: String
            try {
//                val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "/" + HelperClass.FOLDER_NAME)
                val file = File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                    "/" + HelperClass.FOLDER_NAME
                )
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.d("", "Can't create directory to save image.")
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@SmoothActivity.applicationContext,
                            "Can't create directory to save image.",
                            1
                        ).show()
                        return@Runnable
                    }
                }
                val sb = StringBuilder()
                sb.append("Photo_")
                sb.append(System.currentTimeMillis())
                val sb2 = sb.toString()
                str = if (inPNG) {

                    val sb3 = StringBuilder()
                    sb3.append(sb2)
                    sb3.append(".png")
                    sb3.toString()
                } else {
                    val sb4 = StringBuilder()
                    sb4.append(sb2)
                    sb4.append(".jpg")
                    sb4.toString()
                }
                val smoothActivity = this@SmoothActivity
                val sb5 = StringBuilder()
                sb5.append(file.path)
                sb5.append(File.separator)
                sb5.append(str)
                smoothActivity.filename = sb5.toString()
                val file2 = File(filename)
                if (inPNG) {
                    savePNGImage(file2, i)
                    show.dismiss()
                } else {
                    saveJPGImage(file2, i)
                    show.dismiss()
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                show.dismiss()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }).start()
        show.setOnDismissListener { dialogInterface: DialogInterface? ->
            if (showDialog) {
                if (gotoShare) {
                    val applicationContext = this@SmoothActivity.applicationContext
                    val sb = StringBuilder()
                    sb.append(this@SmoothActivity.getString(R.string.saved))
                    sb.append(" ")
                    sb.append(filename)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val intent = Intent(this@SmoothActivity, ShareActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("path", filename)
                    intent.putExtra("showTbg", inPNG)
                    this@SmoothActivity.startActivity(intent)
                    HelperClass.showPopAdWithCount(this)
                    //  HelperClass.showPopAd(SmoothActivity.this);
                    return@setOnDismissListener
                   /* onBackPressed()*/

                }
                val intent = Intent(this@SmoothActivity, BackgroundChangerActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("value", "2")
                this@SmoothActivity.startActivity(intent)
                Log.d("ttpscheckitem",filename.toString()+ "smooth");
               /*onBackPressed()*/
            } else if (gotoShare) {
                val create = AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this@SmoothActivity,
                    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) 16974126 else 16973835
                ).setTitle(this@SmoothActivity.resources.getString(R.string.resolution_error_title))
                    .setMessage(this@SmoothActivity.resources.getString(R.string.rsolution_error_msg))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(this@SmoothActivity.resources.getString(R.string.ok)) { dialogInterface, i1 -> showResolutionOptDialog() }
                    .create()
                create.window!!.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation_
                create.show()
            }
        }
    }
```

get local sorage image ;

final List loadAllImages = loadAllImages(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
this.cutoutAdapter = new CutoutAdapter(this, loadAllImages);
this.cutout_recyclerview.setAdapter(cutoutAdapter);